# MySql - Connection must be valid and open

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-4.0

The following code is throwing the following exception on the line where it calls ExecuteNonQuery() on cmd.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Throw(Exception ex)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Oasis.AlertManager.DB.MySQL.Insert(MySqlCommand cmd) in c:\BuildAgent\work\8b0cd51e92588e6d\Oasis\Oasis.AlertManager.DB\MySQL.cs:line 471

public int Insert(MySqlCommand cmd)
{
    int rows;
    using (masterConnection = new MySqlConnection(masterAlertConnectionStr))
    {
        masterConnection.Open();
        cmd.Connection = masterConnection;
        rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    return rows;
}
```

I am confused because Open() is called on the masterConnection. Has anyone seen this before? Could it be related to the command, or a timeout that's not being set somewhere?

Comment: Normally this error happens when the command isn't associated with the connection - can you show the code where you create the command object?

Comment: I've since discovered that masterConnection is shared by the class, it was not being new'ed up each time in the using statement. Furthermore the same code was being execute by different tasks. I've since changed the using to the following and the exception has gone away :- using(var connection = new MySqlConnection(masterAlertConnectionStr))